# Unable to open JPGs with Fireworks CS5 in Windows XP by right-clicking and choosing "Open With..."

Tags: windows-xp, fireworks

I upgraded from Fireworks CS4 to CS5, and now when I right click on a JPG image and go to "Open With" I do not have Fireworks CS5 as an option. So, I go down to Choose Program and then Fireworks CS5 is no where in the list of programs. So I click Browse and navigate to my Fireworks.exe file and choose it, but it still doesn't appear in my list of available programs. If I navigate to the Fireworks.exe file normally and double-click it, it opens just fine, so I know that there is nothing wrong with my Fireworks program. Also of note: when I right-click on PNG files on my computer, I DO have the option to open in Fireworks CS5 and doing so works perfectly, it's just JPGs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an OS issue. I remember having the same issue even on the Windows XP and 98 days. It's got something to do with file and default application mapping. I'd suggest you rename Fireworks.exe for CS5 to FW5.exe and follow the same steps you described. Since the executable is different, it might work. Otherwise, same exe file is mapped for CS4 and OS is not mapping CS5 even though you are explicitly telling so.